# Cannot bring SQL Server instance online on clustered server

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, failover

I am going to failover my 1st SQL Server instance (`SQL001`) to 2nd Server (Win002) from 1st Server (Win001). Here is the error message in our event log's Application catalog:

> [sqsrvres] OnlineThread: Could not connect to server but server is considered up.

In event log's system catalog:

> Generic service 'GxClusPlugIn (Win001) (Instance001)' could not be brought online (with error '1060') during an attempt to open the service.  Possible causes include: the service is either not installed or the specified service name is invalid.

Did anybody encounter this before and how to fix it?

BTW: my 2nd instance `SQL002` works fine on Win002 and there is no more error message in the event log.

Thanks,

Comment: What research have you done and what troubleshooting have you already attempted?

Comment: better to ask DBA questions on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know this ticket is old. This may be related to the Commvault plugin in different servers with different versions.